# JSON object populate in my html select using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, select

I am a beginner in ajax. Now I am using Laravel 5.4 and I want to populate my cities that I queried in my controller to be output in my view.

Here is my code:

```
function getCities(province_id) {
    $('#city_id').empty();
    $.ajax({         
         url: "{{ url('city') }}/" +province_id,        
         type: "GET",
         dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) {
                var opts = $.parseJSON(data);
                // Use jQuery's each to iterate over the opts value
                $.each(opts, function(i, d) {                    
                    $('#city_id').append('<option value="' + d.city_id + '">' + d.city_name + '</option>');
                });
            }
    }); 
}
```

In my controller, I have this :

```
public function getmycity($province_id) {
        $cities = DB::table('cities')
        ->select('cities.city_id','cities.city_name')
        ->where(['cities.province_id' => $province_id])
        ->get();

        return $cities;
    }
```

I already have a return of json object in my network and I've seen all data objects.

```
JSON    
0   Object
city_id 28
city_name   Test City
```

Please help me to put it all in my select .

I got no error but it doesn't populate my select type with my query values.

here is my view :

```
 <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="email">City/Municipality :</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                   <select class="form-control" id="city_id" name="city_id">
                        <option>Select city/municipality</option>                   
                    </select>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Hi, if your getmycity  method is returning JSON properly then select dropdown should be populated accordingly. Please see it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/tjg8rmgu/2/

Comment: Or you can check by using following line  return response()->json($cities); in getmycity method.

Comment: @Rakib please help me sir still the answer is not the solution to my problem

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: Just remove JSON.parse in the success method: var opts = data;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your db result in pure array like this:

```
$cities = json_decode(json_encode($cities),true);
```

Then `return` it:

```
return $cities;
```

And,
when you have written dataType : 'JSON' then no need to parse your response,Can you try without `var opts = $.parseJSON(data);` like this `var opts = data;`

Hope this would help you...

Comment: hey Jc John, I am glad that my answer helped you. Can I get an up vote please ?
Thank you so much... :-)

Comment: opps hello sir @Himanshu i thought it would already solved my problem but still its not populating

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: i added my view

Comment: when you have written dataType : 'JSON' then no need to parse your response, 
Can you try without `var opts = $.parseJSON(data);` like this `var opts = data;`

Comment: ok, Putting this comment in my answer. It would be useful to others too. Can I have one Up vote please?
Thanks in advance....

Comment: I don't think it's a good practice to send JSON like this way:  `$cities = json_decode(json_encode($cities),true);`

Comment: Laravel will make json itself. We do this to make APIs. Documented in Laravel official website.

Comment: return response()->json($cities); then why we are not using this instead of encoding and decoding. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#json-responses

Comment: @John please use this: return response()->json($cities); and read document here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#json-responses

Comment: yes, but json_decode and encode was used to make query result into pure array. Sometimes if would be combination of array with objects.
And with ajax/httpx request, return $cities works fine. 
That's why it was up voted. It helped who has asked the question.